# How do you send to Transunion API with pkcs12 (p12) certificate?

Tags: php, api, curl, certificate

I am having trouble connecting to TransUnion's test API via php using cURL. Please let me know if anyone has already done this. I already have my XML file ready to send to them, I just don't know what is the problem because I received a .p12 file from them that contains the certificate and key but still it's not letting me connect. I tried the following:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd().'/certs/cert.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'test_pass');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, 'PEM');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, getcwd().'/certs/key.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, 'test_pass');
```

Then I tried connecting via Terminal on my mac using:

```
curl -cert /Users/temp_user/cert.pem   -key /Users/temp_user/key.pem https://netaccess-test.transunion.com
```

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Which error do you get back? With curl, try the verbose switch (-v at the commandline and the related option in PHP with curl_setopt) to learn more about what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I used OpenSSL on the command line to create both a certificate(cert.pem) and key(key.pem) files from the .p12 file. But yeah, I received the following when I added --verbose to the command line:             <error>
<errorcode>
40
</errorcode>
<errortext>
The digital certificate is invalid. Please ensure you have the correct digital certificate or download a new digital certificate, and then resubmit the transactions. if the situation persists, notify the TransUnion Service Desk at 800-813-5604.
</errortext>
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):

Comment: Check if you did convert it correctly. Also for testing reasons I think you can remove the password from these. Can be helpful while you trouble-shoot.

Comment: Im not sure of a way of how to do that. Even though a .p12 is a keystore, is it possible to send that type of file via cURL?

Comment: Did you end up with the solution? I'm stuck in the same problem, would really appreciate if you could share a solution, please? :(

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older post but since I came across it while trying to figure out the connection issues I was having with TransUnion, I figured I'd post what I did to get it working in case anyone else still needs help with this.

I worked with TransUnion support team to combine what I had and the info they had and I was able to get a working solution.

The biggest issue that I found was the instructions all over the place for how to convert the cert.

Use the below commands to convert the cert in order to get the needed pieces to use for the connection.  Yes you need 3, most answers out there kept saying to only get 2 but you need all 3:

Convert the certificate into three different certificates for the client, the private key and the certification authority certificate.

openssl pkcs12 -in client_systemID.p12 -out ca.pem -cacerts -nokeys //Outputs CA certificates from .p12 file into ca.pem

openssl pkcs12 -in client_systemID.p12 -out client.pem -clcerts -nokeys //Outputs client certificates from.p12 file into client.pem

openssl pkcs12 -in client_systemID.p12 -out key.pem -nocerts -nodes //Outputs private keys from.p12 into key.pem

Then you can start setting up your code:

```
$keyFile = "key.pem";
$caFile = "ca.pem";
$certFile = "client.pem";
$certPass = $_ENV['TUNASSLPass']; //I am storing the passphrase in an Env variable
$URL = "https://netaccess-test.transunion.com";
$data = "<tuna-request-data>"; //need to set this to append to the URL
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><creditBureau xmlns='http://www.transunion.com/namespace' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.transunion.com/namespace creditBureau.xsd' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/3001/XMLSchema-instance'>{The rest of your XML}</creditBureau>";

// Initialise cURL
$ch = curl_init($actualUrl);

// The -d option is equivalent to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. But...
// PHP's libcurl interface does not implement the -G flag - instead you would
// append $data to $url like this:
$actualUrl = $URL.'?'.$data;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $actualUrl);

// The -v flag only makes sense at the command line, but it can be enabled
// with CURLOPT_VERBOSE - in this case the information will be written to
// STDERR, or the file specified by CURLOPT_STDERR. I will ignore this for
// now, but if you would like a demonstration let me know.

// The --key option - If your key file has a password, you will need to set
// this with CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyFile);

// The --cacert option
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $caFile);

// The --cert option
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $certPass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "xml=" . $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
try
{
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo 'There was an issue querying TransUnion.  Here is the returned exception info: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

if (curl_errno($ch) > 0)
{
    $result = array('errocurl' => curl_errno($ch), 'msgcurl' => curl_error($ch));
    echo "There was an error calling Trans Union.  Here is the error info: <br>" . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I agree that instructions seem to be all over the place for this, which is typical for cURL-related things in PHP. I don't know if this relegated to PHP though, as I find the php.net docs very useful and understandable most of the time. A lot of my implementation with security and network functions like these are typically trial-and-error most of the time, probably because it takes understanding a lot of the underlying tech (good luck with that) to easily understand how to make it work in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you extract your certificates correctly from the p12 file like so:

To extract the CA Certificate:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in NAME_OF_P12_FILE.p12 -cacerts -nokeys -out NAME_OF_PEM_FILE_TO_CREATE.pem
```

To extract the Personal Certificate:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in NAME_OF_P12_FILE.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out NAME_OF_PEM_FILE_TO_CREATE.pem
```

To extract the Private Key:

With a password: `openssl pkcs12 -in NAME_OF_P12_FILE.p12 -clcerts -nocerts -out NAME_OF_PEM_FILE_TO_CREATE.pem`

Without a password: `openssl pkcs12 -in NAME_OF_P12_FILE.p12 -clcerts -nocerts -nodes -out NAME_OF_PEM_FILE_TO_CREATE.pem`